# Collapsing Images contained in Fluid Grid View

Tags: views, theming

[image: Images contained in Fluid Grid]

Hi there. I would be very grateful for your help.

I have images contained in fluid grid (D7 module), all of them are initially collapsed (just like the img on the bottom left) upon site loading. What I need to do is to right-click the collapsed bar then it will be shown ('cause left-clicking will direct me to its link). This is happening on my chrome browser; FF works fine. I am currently using a sub-theme of Creative Responsive Theme.

What I already did to hopefully resolve the problem was to uninstall the module then re-install; undo changes to my .content a img {... }; clear all cache; but still no luck. Also, I have read docs about the theme and the module, there are no inclusions regarding this error.

Comment: If you change to a drupal default theme, like bartik, this doesn't happen?